# YouTube API lists offline Livestreams as video

Tags: python, pandas, youtube-api

I need a list of all videos from a YouTube channel using the YouTube Data API. I used the Upload-Playlist to get this list. But I discovered, that this list contains offline livestreams as well. Does anyone know how to detect, if the type of the item is a video or livestream? In the JSON from the request is a `type` argument, but this says e.g.: `'resourceId': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'Rul7Z2pkH1w'}`.

I'm working with Python and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

channel = 'UC192SEGl9dAng9GwredMSww'
api_key = '...'
# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['channel_id',
                           'video_id',
                           'video_title',
                           'published_date',
                           'type'])

playlist_id = channel[:1] + 'U' + channel[2:]

url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&part=snippet&part=status&playlistId=' + playlist_id + '&maxResults=50&key=' + api_key
response = requests.get(url=url).json()

# save the channel_id and video_id in a dataframe
for i in response['items']:
    channel_id = i['snippet']['channelId']
    video_id = i['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
    published_date = i['snippet']['publishedAt']
    video_title = i['snippet']['title']
    vid_type = i['snippet']['resourceId']['kind']

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([{
        'channel_id': channel_id,
        'video_id': video_id,
        'video_title': video_title,
        'published_date': published_date,
        'type': vid_type
    }])], ignore_index=True)

    url2 = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&part=id&part=statistics&part=localizations&part=status&part=contentDetails&part=liveStreamingDetails&part=topicDetails&id=' + video_id + '&maxResults=50&key=' + api_key
    response2 = requests.get(url=url).json()

    print(response2)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your code - especially from the `response2` variable, get the value of [snippet.liveBroadcastContent](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.liveBroadcastContent) path and see if the value is: ***none***.

Quote from the documentation:

> **`snippet.liveBroadcastContent`**    `string`
>
> Indicates if the video is an
> upcoming/active live broadcast. Or it's "none" if the video is not an
> upcoming/active live broadcast.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - live
> - none
> - upcoming

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857505/7123660):

By using YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#liveStreamingDetails) you can distinguish videos from livestreams.

For the video id [`Rul7Z2pkH1w`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rul7Z2pkH1w) you shared, that is a livestream waiting to start you'll get:

```
"liveStreamingDetails": {
    "scheduledStartTime": "2018-07-01T18:27:49Z",
    "activeLiveChatId": "Cg0KC1J1bDdaMnBrSDF3KicKGFVDMTkyU0VHbDlkQW5nOUd3cmVkTVN3dxILUnVsN1oycGtIMXc"
}
```

For a video such as [`mWdFMNQBcjs`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWdFMNQBcjs), you wouldn't get any JSON entry `liveStreamingDetails`.

For an ended livestream such as [`TCBbXgBIC1I`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCBbXgBIC1I), you'll get:

```
"liveStreamingDetails": {
    "actualStartTime": "2022-08-05T11:45:13Z",
    "actualEndTime": "2022-08-05T11:45:54Z"
}
```