# Refining Python Script for Efficient YouTube Channel Data Extraction and Organization

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, youtube-api, extract, youtube-data-api

I am immersed in a personal project focused on organizing a YouTube channel, and I am facing specific challenges that need addressing. On YouTube, there are three main types of content: *VIDEOS*, *SHORTS* and *LIVE*.

**Context of Content Types on YouTube:**
***VIDEOS***: The traditional YouTube format with no duration restrictions.
***SHORTS***: Short videos, up to 60 seconds, in vertical format.
***LIVE***: Live broadcasts that encourage real-time interaction with the audience.

**Challenge in the *VIDEOS* Section:**
In the *VIDEOS* section of YouTube, diversity is noticeable. It includes scheduled live stream videos and short clips that do not fit the *SHORTS* categorization.
Scheduled live stream videos: Creators schedule broadcasts for specific dates and times. These videos appear in *VIDEOS* and not in *LIVE*.
Uncategorized short clips: Videos with a duration of 60 seconds or less that do not meet specific requirements to be classified as "SHORTS" (such as vertical format, among others).

It is relevant to mention that I am using the YouTube Data API v3 to extract information efficiently.

I would like to share that I am relatively new to this field and am in the learning process. I appreciate your patience and any guidance you can provide. If you notice any clumsiness in my approach, I would be delighted to receive advice for improvement.

Here is the relevant portion of my Python script, YouTube Channel Scraper:

```
import os
import re
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Function to extract YouTube channel ID from the provided link
def get_channel_id(channel_link):
    try:
        # Make a request to the provided YouTube channel link
        response = requests.get(channel_link)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Define a regex pattern to extract the channel ID from the XML feed link
            pattern = r"https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml\?channel_id=([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"
            # Search for the pattern in the response text
            match = re.search(pattern, response.text)

            # If a match is found, return the extracted channel ID
            if match:
                return match.group(1)
            else:
                print("No channel found in the provided link.")
        else:
            print("Could not access the link. Make sure the link is valid.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred while making the request:", str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))

    return None

# Function to parse the duration string and extract hours, minutes, and seconds
def parse_duration(duration):
    duration = duration[2:]
    hours, minutes, seconds = 0, 0, 0

    if 'H' in duration:
        hours = int(duration.split('H')[0])
        duration = duration.split('H')[1]
    if 'M' in duration:
        minutes = int(duration.split('M')[0])
        duration = duration.split('M')[1]
    if 'S' in duration:
        seconds = int(duration.split('S')[0])

    return hours, minutes, seconds

# Function to save video information to a file
def save_video_info_to_file(output_file, video_info):
    title = video_info["snippet"]["title"]
    views = video_info["statistics"].get("viewCount", "N/A")
    likes = video_info["statistics"].get("likeCount", "N/A")
    upload_date = video_info["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
    hours, minutes, seconds = parse_duration(video_info["contentDetails"]["duration"])

    # Convert upload date to GMT-5 timezone, this is my time zone
    upload_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(upload_date[:-1])
    upload_datetime_gmt5 = upload_datetime - timedelta(hours=5)

    # Adjust for videos uploaded before 5 AM GMT-5
    if upload_datetime_gmt5.hour < 5:
        upload_datetime_gmt5 -= timedelta(days=1)

    formatted_upload_date = upload_datetime_gmt5.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    formatted_upload_time = upload_datetime_gmt5.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    duration_str = ""
    if hours > 0:
        duration_str += f"{hours} hour{'s' if hours > 1 else ''}"
    if minutes > 0:
        if duration_str:
            duration_str += ", "
        duration_str += f"{minutes} minute{'s' if minutes > 1 else ''}"
    if seconds > 0:
        if duration_str:
            duration_str += " and "
        duration_str += f"{seconds} second{'s' if seconds > 1 else ''}"

    # Write video information to the output file
    with open(output_file, "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("Title: " + title + "\n")
        file.write("Upload Date: " + formatted_upload_date + "\n")
        file.write("Upload Time: " + formatted_upload_time + "\n")
        file.write("Duration: " + duration_str + "\n")
        file.write("Views: " + str(views) + "\n")
        file.write("Likes: " + str(likes) + "\n\n\n")

# Function to get channel name and save video information to a file
def get_channel_name(channel_id):
    api_key = "[YOUR API HERE]"
    gmt_offset = -5

    # Build the YouTube API service
    youtube = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=api_key)

    videos_info = []

    # Fetch videos information from the channel
    next_page_token = None
    while True:
        videos_response = youtube.search().list(
            part="id",
            channelId=channel_id,
            maxResults=50,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()

        video_ids = [item["id"]["videoId"] for item in videos_response.get("items", []) if "videoId" in item.get("id", {})]

        videos_details_response = youtube.videos().list(
            part="snippet,statistics,contentDetails",
            id=",".join(video_ids)
        ).execute()

        videos_info.extend(videos_details_response["items"])

        next_page_token = videos_response.get("nextPageToken")
        if not next_page_token:
            break

    videos_info.sort(key=lambda x: x["snippet"]["publishedAt"], reverse=True)

    # Fetch channel information
    channel_info = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet",
        id=channel_id
    ).execute()

    # Get the channel name or use a default if not available
    if channel_info.get("items"):
        channel_name = channel_info["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
    else:
        channel_name = "Unknown Channel"

    # Modify the channel name for file naming
    channel_name = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', channel_name)
    channel_name = channel_name.replace(" ", "_")

    # Set the output file name
    output_file = f"{channel_name}.txt"

    # Save video information to the output file
    for video_info in videos_info:
        save_video_info_to_file(output_file, video_info)

    print("Information has been saved to the file:", output_file)

# Entry point of the script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Prompt user to input the YouTube channel link
    channel_link = input("Enter the YouTube channel link: ")
    # Get the channel ID from the provided link
    channel_id = get_channel_id(channel_link)
    # If a valid channel ID is obtained, get the channel name and save video information
    if channel_id:
        get_channel_name(channel_id)
```

My goal is to refine the script to achieve more accurate and efficient classification, considering these complexities.

I've been diving into the intricacies of refining this Python script for efficient YouTube channel data extraction and organization. In my attempts so far, I experimented with optimizing the regex patterns for better channel ID extraction and fine-tuning the duration parsing logic.

I expected these adjustments to enhance the script's accuracy in classifying videos, especially in the 'VIDEOS' section. However, the results were not as anticipated. I'm reaching out for your expertise to gain fresh insights and suggestions.

I appreciate in advance for your valuable contribution and patience!

Comment: Do these answers concerning [livestreams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857534) and [shorts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71194751) solve your problem?